# Is there a bsxfun type function for vectors in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, bsxfun

Specifically, I'm trying to create a kernel matrix from a kernel function which takes vectors as inputs and produces a scalar as an output. The kernel matrix, then, is a the 2D matrix of such outputs for each pair of vectors.

In the case of the vector inputs themselves being 1D, I can use bsxfun do to this:

`x = [1;2;3;4];
kerfun = @(s,t) (s-t)   % some function, doesn't matter, except that it returns a scalar
kernel = bsxfun(kerfun, x, x');`

The output is the kernel, as expected:

```
kernel =

     0    -1    -2    -3
     1     0    -1    -2
     2     1     0    -1
     3     2     1     0
```

However, if I change the points in `x` into N-D vectors, this approach fails. My question is: Is there an efficient way to construct the kernel matrix without using loops? I tried using cellfun but that didn't seem to work either. Thanks.

Edit: As an example of the expected outcomes, if I change `x` and `kerfun` as follows:

```
x = [1,15;23,2;13,5;4,7];
kerfun = @(s,t) norm(s-t); %some function, returns a scalar
ker = zeros(4,4);
```

then compute the kernel by brute force:

```
for i=1:size(x,1)
    for j=1:size(x,1)
        ker(i,j) = kerfun(x(i,:),x(j,:));
    end
end
```

I get:

```
ker =

         0   25.5539   15.6205    8.5440
   25.5539         0   10.4403   19.6469
   15.6205   10.4403         0    9.2195
    8.5440   19.6469    9.2195         0
```

Comment: Can you show us an example input and expected output? `bsxfun` can work with any dimension input if it's the right shape

Comment: Hey Suever, I've updated the the question. Please take a look now. I hope this clarifies the question I'm asking - I'd like a function (like bsxfun) to return a matrix of function evaluations not element-wise but vector-wise. Feeding the list of vectors (as in x in the second example) causes bsxfun to crash as x and x' aren't usually the same size. Besides, the numbers in the matrix would be wrong and not the droids I'm looking for.

Comment: You're doing filter/convolution, right?

Comment: Gaussian processes, actually...

Answer (score 1):

[`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) can be used with *N*-dimensional arrays, and it will expand their singleton dimensions. But it works element-wise. If you want a function that does some "aggregating" operation along rows, as in your example, `bsxfun` can only do the element-wise part (with singleton expansion). You then need to complement with some other aggregating function to get the final result.

For the specific case in your example, the function you want can be decomposed as element-wise subtraction (this is where `bsxfun` enters), then sum along rows (the aggregating part), then element-wise square root. To do the subtraction with `bsxfun` you need to permute the first dimension of a copy of `x` onto the third dimension. That way the first and third dimensions span all combinations of `i` and `j` in your two loops.

Then sum along the second dimension of the resulting 3D array, take the square root, and permute back to have a matrix result:

```
ker = sqrt(permute(sum(bsxfun(@minus, x, permute(x, [3 2 1])).^2, 2), [1 3 2]));
```

Note that it's faster to use one of the `bsxfun`'s builtin functions (like `minus` here) than a custom function.

For `x = [1,15;23,2;13,5;4,7]` this produces

```
ker =
         0   25.5539   15.6205    8.5440
   25.5539         0   10.4403   19.6469
   15.6205   10.4403         0    9.2195
    8.5440   19.6469    9.2195         0
```